# Change MS Office control size with Microsoft Active Accessibility

Tags: ms-office

I'd like to change the width of the "Document Location" in my QAT (= Quick Access Toolbar). Is this possible with Microsoft Active Accessibility? Unfortunately I'm not yet familiar with it.

Thanks, Michael

Comment: Pretty sure it isn't. MSAA just takes the UI information and makes it available to assistive technology. Not quite sure what you're talking about, so I can't give too much info

Comment: Yeah, it was/is kind a silly question. I thought that it might be possible to get a handle (of the controls inside the QAT) with MAA. Then I could change the size with autohotkey. But there seems to be no way to change the size of an element of the QAT. MAA was the only way (I found) to at least access the controls of a NetUIHWND. So I let myself be carried away by this rash question.

Comment: another thing is you may try to bump down either your  resolution or your PPI. That will make everything bigger. If it is the QAT I am thinking of, you can press alt, then whatever you place in the QAT is accessed by 1-7.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'll have to look for another solution or a workaround. I'd like to see the whole path and not just the beginning.

Comment: What do you mean by whole path?

Comment: The text box of the "Document Location" has a certain length. If the path is longer, not all characters can be displayed.

Comment: OK, yeah that is a hack with the UI.